# How to Align a Div in the Center of Another Div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div sit in the direct center of another div. I tried to use `margin: auto;` to accomplish this, but the div only aligned in the center horizontally. How can I apply this for a center vertical align?

```css
.topbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #131218;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.body {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 330px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  float: left;
  will-change: transform;
  animation: logofloat 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes logofloat {
  from {
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(15px);
  }
}

.authdiv {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <img class="logo" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/fff/000.png&text=Logo">
</div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="authdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: adding a codesandbox/working preview will help to resolve the problem quickly.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Unfortunately, no. I was able to center the div horizontally. My issue is trying to center it vertically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center div horizontally and vertically inside another div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478216/center-div-horizontally-and-vertically-inside-another-div) But there are far too many same questions with same answers, found by just searching SO, and which should almost all be closed as duplicates like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) on your containing element:

```css
.topbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #131218;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 330px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

img {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 200px;
  float: left;
  will-change: transform;
  animation: logofloat 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes logofloat {
  from {
    transform: translateY(5px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(15px);
  }
}

.authdiv {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <img class="logo" src="https://dummyimage.com/50x50/fff/000.png&text=Logo">
</div>
<div class="body">
  <div class="authdiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I usually put the element i want to center at 50% from top and 50% from left. Then use translate to pull the element back half it's size. So just add the 4 lines below.

```
.authdiv {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: auto;

  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50% , -50%);
}
```

Comment: this also works in IE11